# imread throws error when file is copy pasted into folder

Tags: python

I have a script that will process all the image in a folder whenever there is new file coming in

```
while (True):
    for _, _, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files:
            img = cv2.imread(f'{source}/{file}')
            print(img.size)
```

this works well when

- I already have file in the folder before running the script
- Cut and paste file into the folder when the script is already running

this breaks when

- I copy and paste file into the folder when the script is already running

The error that I got is

```
Exception in thread process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "vacOcr.py", line 36, in ocrDecode
    print(img.size)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error fixed by using

```
try:
    img = cv2.imread(f'{source}/{file}')
    print(img.size)
except:
    continue
```

I think it's because when you copy the file over, it takes some time to complete the whole copy process, and the script is already trying to read the file which is imcomplete. Correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: This means now you skip thise files? Is that really your wanted behaviour?

Comment: Yes it is skipping temporarily, but since it's in a infinite loop, the script will get back to that file in the next iteration